# Searching for a folder name in a server in Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
IF EXIST \\SERVERNAME\DIRECTORY\FOLDERNAME\ 
echo "set a Variable value here"
```

The variable value is not being set despite folder existing in the directory in the server.  I need to assign a value to a variable if the folder exists in the server location. However, the above code is not doing that. Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: You cannot split the command line into two separate lines...

Answer (score 0):

Untested as I am on my phone, but something like this should work.

```
@echo off
set folder="\\computer\DIRECTORY\FOLDERNAME"
if exist %folder% (
    echo %folder%) else echo %folder% Does Not Exist
```

Obviously we are just echoing that the folder exists or not here, but that is where you would change it to set the variable.

Obviously this would also work in single line.

```
IF EXIST "\\SERVERNAME\DIRECTORY\FOLDERNAME\" echo "set a Variable value here"
```